# Laravel: Combining the results with UnionAll and where conditions

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Lets just say I have 2 tables

**resume_profiles Table:**

```
   user_id  current_location      city
   | 3 |     | Chennai  |    | Kolkatta   |
   | 4 |     | Mumbai   |    | Ahmaedabad |
   | 5 |     | Pune     |    | Kolkatta   |
   | 6 |     | Kolkatta |    | Pune       |
```

**resume_locations Table:**

```
   user_id     location
   | 2 |     | Chennai  |
   | 2 |     | Mumbai   |
   | 3 |     | Pune     |
   | 4 |     | Kolkatta |
```

I need to combine these result table locations into a single SET where resume_profiles.user_id = resume_locations.user_id using Union ALL, So I'd have something like this:

```
   City        Aggregate
| Chennai    |    | 1 |
| Mumbai     |    | 1 |
| Pune       |    | 2 |
| Kolkatta   |    | 3 |
| Ahmaedabad |    | 1 |
```

**Working Query without where user_id:**

```
$preferred_locations = ResumeLocation::selectRaw('location as city');

$current_locations = ResumeProfile::selectRaw('current_location as city');

$subquery = ResumeProfile::selectRaw('city')
            ->unionAll($current_locations)
            ->unionAll($preferred_locations);

$locations = DB::table(DB::raw("({$subquery->toSql()}) AS s"))
            ->selectRaw('s.city,count(*) as aggregate')
            ->groupBy('s.city')
            ->get();
```

** Getting Exception in Query while using were condition :**

```
$preferred_locations = ResumeLocation::selectRaw('location as city')
            ->where('resume_locations.user_id','resume_profiles.user_id');

$current_locations = ResumeProfile::selectRaw('current_location as city');

$subquery = ResumeProfile::selectRaw('city')
            ->unionAll($current_locations)
            ->unionAll($preferred_locations);

$locations = DB::table(DB::raw("({$subquery->toSql()}) AS s"))
            ->selectRaw('s.city,count(*) as aggregate')
            ->groupBy('s.city')
            ->get();
```

I don't know how to achieve this `where` condition in a table.

Comment: you can't use where with columns from a different table. you can join or use whereIn

Comment: can you please share the whereIn condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**whereIn**:

```
$preferred_locations = ResumeLocation::selectRaw('location as city')
->whereIn('user_id', function($q) {
  $q->select('user_id')->from('resume_profiles');
});
```